# Number of elements in a group formed by matrices with elements in $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I was reading the book Topics in Algebra, by Herstein, when I encontered the following question:

> Given a prime number $ p$, how many elements has the group formed by matrices  $M \in M_2$, where $M = \begin{pmatrix}
>         a & b\\
>         c & d\\
>         \end{pmatrix}$, with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z_p$,
>   and $ad-bd \neq 0$.

My first idea wa to count the total number of matrices satisfying the first condition, then remove the ones which have determinant equal to $0$.  I started by separting cases: when $a,b,c \neq 0 $; $a,b \neq 0$, and going on. This aproach, however, leads to such a great number of subcases I coud not manage. Is there a more interesting way to reach the answer?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is the very classical question of the number of elements of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z_p})$ (here $n=2$) and more generally of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z_q})$ with $q=p^k$. See for example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) where a formula is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. We count the solutions of $ad=bc$  in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

i) If $a=0$ then there are $p$ choices for $d$ and $p^2-(p-1)^2=2p-1$ for $b$ and $c$ (at least one has to be zero).

ii) If $a\neq 0$ then $d=bc/a$. Hence there are $p-1$ choices for $a$, $p$ for $b$ and $p$ for $c$.

P.S. Hence the total number of matrices of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z_p})$ is
$$p^4-[p(2p-1)+(p-1)p^2]=p(p+1)(p-1)^2.$$
A general formula for $GL(n,\mathbb{Z_p})$ can be found here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields

Comment: For i) if $b=c$ you must count them only once. Similar for ii)

Comment: @Eugen Covaci They are counted once.

Comment: OK, but for ii) $b, c$ cannot be zero, so you don't have $p$ choices for $b$ and $c$

Comment: @Eugen Covaci In ii) $b$ and $c$ can be zero!

Comment: If $b=0$ then $d=0$ and $ad=bc=0$ (also with $a\not=0$)

Comment: OK, sorry, my mistake

Comment: @Eugen Covaci I double check is welcome! :-)

Comment: Thank you @RobertZ, very clever (to me, at least :)), and also you Eugen , for observations

Comment: @mateus A Good! Don't forget to accept my answer if it was useful ;-) http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: @mateus A Take a look at this page http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the best way to count invertible matrices is to count the number of distinct bases of $\mathbb Z_p^2$, which is given by
$$
(p^ 2 -1 ) \cdot (p^ 2 - p),
$$
where the first factor counts the choices for the first element of the basis, which is just any non-zero vectors, and the second the vectors that are not multiples of the first one.

Comment: and then, expand to a general case, maybe using inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: For $n \times n$ matrices, it will be $(p^n-1)(p^{n}-p) \cdots (p^n - p^{n-1} ) $.